# Problems starting a process from a DLL in Windows Server 2008

Tags: c#, process, windows-server-2008

I have a DLL which starts up some basic Windows programs:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace ExternalProgram
{
    public class Access
    {
        String applicationName = String.Empty;

        public Access()
        {
        }

        public void Telnet(string address)
        {
            applicationName = "telnet.exe " + address;

            ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
            ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(applicationName, out procInfo);
        }

        public void Ping(string address)
        {
            Process.Start("ping.exe", address + " -t"); 

            //applicationName = "ping.exe " + address + " -t";

            //ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
            //ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(applicationName, out procInfo);
        }

        public void Putty(string address)
        {
            applicationName = "putty.exe " + address;

            ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
            ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(applicationName, out procInfo);
        }

        public void RemoteDesktop(string address)
        {
            applicationName = "mstsc.exe " + "/v " + address;

            ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
            ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(applicationName, out procInfo);
        }

        public void Browse(string address)
        {
            applicationName = GetDefaultBrowser() + " " + address;

            ApplicationLoader.PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo;
            ApplicationLoader.StartProcessAndBypassUAC(applicationName, out procInfo);
        }

        private string GetDefaultBrowser()
        {
            string browser = string.Empty;
            RegistryKey key = null;

            try
            {
                key = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(@"HTTP\shell\open\command", false);

                //trim off quotes
                browser = key.GetValue(null).ToString().ToLower().Replace("\"", "");
                if (!browser.EndsWith("exe"))
                {
                    //get rid of everything after the ".exe"
                    browser = browser.Substring(0, browser.LastIndexOf(".exe") + 4);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (key != null) key.Close();
            }
            return browser;
        }
    }
}

namespace ExternalProgram
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Class that allows running applications with full admin rights. In
    /// addition the application launched will bypass the Vista UAC prompt.
    /// </summary>
    public class ApplicationLoader
    {
        #region Structures

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
        {
            public int Length;
            public IntPtr lpSecurityDescriptor;
            public bool bInheritHandle;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct STARTUPINFO
        {
            public int cb;
            public String lpReserved;
            public String lpDesktop;
            public String lpTitle;
            public uint dwX;
            public uint dwY;
            public uint dwXSize;
            public uint dwYSize;
            public uint dwXCountChars;
            public uint dwYCountChars;
            public uint dwFillAttribute;
            public uint dwFlags;
            public short wShowWindow;
            public short cbReserved2;
            public IntPtr lpReserved2;
            public IntPtr hStdInput;
            public IntPtr hStdOutput;
            public IntPtr hStdError;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct PROCESS_INFORMATION
        {
            public IntPtr hProcess;
            public IntPtr hThread;
            public uint dwProcessId;
            public uint dwThreadId;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Enumerations

        enum TOKEN_TYPE : int
        {
            TokenPrimary = 1,
            TokenImpersonation = 2
        }

        enum SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL : int
        {
            SecurityAnonymous = 0,
            SecurityIdentification = 1,
            SecurityImpersonation = 2,
            SecurityDelegation = 3,
        }

        #endregion

        #region Constants

        public const int TOKEN_DUPLICATE = 0x0002;
        public const uint MAXIMUM_ALLOWED = 0x2000000;
        public const int CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE = 0x00000010;

        public const int IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x40;
        public const int NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x20;
        public const int HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x80;
        public const int REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x100;

        #endregion

        #region Win32 API Imports

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr hSnapshot);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern uint WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "CreateProcessAsUser", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
        public extern static bool CreateProcessAsUser(IntPtr hToken, String lpApplicationName, String lpCommandLine, ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpProcessAttributes,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, bool bInheritHandle, int dwCreationFlags, IntPtr lpEnvironment,
            String lpCurrentDirectory, ref STARTUPINFO lpStartupInfo, out PROCESS_INFORMATION lpProcessInformation);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool ProcessIdToSessionId(uint dwProcessId, ref uint pSessionId);

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DuplicateTokenEx")]
        public extern static bool DuplicateTokenEx(IntPtr ExistingTokenHandle, uint dwDesiredAccess,
            ref SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES lpThreadAttributes, int TokenType,
            int ImpersonationLevel, ref IntPtr DuplicateTokenHandle);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern IntPtr OpenProcess(uint dwDesiredAccess, bool bInheritHandle, uint dwProcessId);

        [DllImport("advapi32", SetLastError = true), SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurityAttribute]
        static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr ProcessHandle, int DesiredAccess, ref IntPtr TokenHandle);

        #endregion

        /// <summary>
        /// Launches the given application with full admin rights, and in addition bypasses the Vista UAC prompt
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="applicationName">The name of the application to launch</param>
        /// <param name="procInfo">Process information regarding the launched application that gets returned to the caller</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static bool StartProcessAndBypassUAC(String applicationName, out PROCESS_INFORMATION procInfo)
        {
            uint winlogonPid = 0;
            IntPtr hUserTokenDup = IntPtr.Zero, hPToken = IntPtr.Zero, hProcess = IntPtr.Zero;
            procInfo = new PROCESS_INFORMATION();

            // obtain the currently active session id; every logged on user in the system has a unique session id
            uint dwSessionId = WTSGetActiveConsoleSessionId();

            // obtain the process id of the winlogon process that is running within the currently active session
            Process[] processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("winlogon");
            foreach (Process p in processes)
            {
                if ((uint)p.SessionId == dwSessionId)
                {
                    winlogonPid = (uint)p.Id;
                }
            }

            // obtain a handle to the winlogon process
            hProcess = OpenProcess(MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, false, winlogonPid);

            // obtain a handle to the access token of the winlogon process
            if (!OpenProcessToken(hProcess, TOKEN_DUPLICATE, ref hPToken))
            {
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                return false;
            }

            // Security attibute structure used in DuplicateTokenEx and CreateProcessAsUser
            // I would prefer to not have to use a security attribute variable and to just 
            // simply pass null and inherit (by default) the security attributes
            // of the existing token. However, in C# structures are value types and therefore
            // cannot be assigned the null value.
            SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES sa = new SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES();
            sa.Length = Marshal.SizeOf(sa);

            // copy the access token of the winlogon process; the newly created token will be a primary token
            if (!DuplicateTokenEx(hPToken, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, ref sa, (int)SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.SecurityIdentification, (int)TOKEN_TYPE.TokenPrimary, ref hUserTokenDup))
            {
                CloseHandle(hProcess);
                CloseHandle(hPToken);
                return false;
            }

            // By default CreateProcessAsUser creates a process on a non-interactive window station, meaning
            // the window station has a desktop that is invisible and the process is incapable of receiving
            // user input. To remedy this we set the lpDesktop parameter to indicate we want to enable user 
            // interaction with the new process.
            STARTUPINFO si = new STARTUPINFO();
            si.cb = (int)Marshal.SizeOf(si);
            si.lpDesktop = @"winsta0\default"; // interactive window station parameter; basically this indicates that the process created can display a GUI on the desktop

            // flags that specify the priority and creation method of the process
            int dwCreationFlags = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;

            // create a new process in the current user's logon session
            bool result = CreateProcessAsUser(hUserTokenDup,        // client's access token
                                            null,                   // file to execute
                                            applicationName,        // command line
                                            ref sa,                 // pointer to process SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                            ref sa,                 // pointer to thread SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
                                            false,                  // handles are not inheritable
                                            dwCreationFlags,        // creation flags
                                            IntPtr.Zero,            // pointer to new environment block 
                                            null,                   // name of current directory 
                                            ref si,                 // pointer to STARTUPINFO structure
                                            out procInfo            // receives information about new process
                                            );

            // invalidate the handles
            CloseHandle(hProcess);
            CloseHandle(hPToken);
            CloseHandle(hUserTokenDup);

            return result; // return the result
        }

    }
}
```

The `ApplicationLoader` code I snagged from a blog online about bypassing Vista UAC. When I first wrote the code I noticed that the process would start, but that it would not be visible to the user, you could only see/kill the process through the process manager.

The third-party `ApplicationLoader` code resolved this issue on Vista and Win7. I am able to see the process happily start and run fine.

I just moved the DLL over to Windows Server 2008 and I am not seeing the process start at all. No errors, no warnings. I disabled UAC on the server, rebooted, tried again and I saw no change.

I tried starting the process regularly as well as starting it using the application loader, no dice. It does start fine from `Run()`, though, so it is my code.

Any ideas? Where do I begin on error logging for something like this? Do I still need the `ApplicationLoader` code at all, or is it breaking in Server 2008?

EDIT: I was able to track this issues further. The process is starting up successfully, but then immediately becomes not visible while loading DLLs. I've seen this written about on Google, so I'm looking, but any other advice would be appreciated.

EDIT2: Discovery! Logging in as Administrator instead of a user with administrative privileges yields different results -- process is alive but not visible.

EDIT: I HAVE IDENTIFIED THE ISSUE AND HAVE NO IDEA TO SOLVE. Would love help.

So, here is what's going on in two different scenarios:

Scenario 1: Windows 7 (WORKING)

If I go to Start->Run->Ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -t and then open Task Manager I see PING.EXE opened under SEAN running in SESSION 1.

If I run Ping.exe using Process.Start() PING.EXE opens up under SYSTEM running in SESSION 0. It is invisible because it is not running in the same session as I am currently working under.

If I run Ping.exe using StartProcessAndBypassUAC PING.EXE opens up under SYSTEM running in SESSION 1. It is visible to me. Of note, the session ID here is the same as when I manually run ping.

Scenario 2: Windows Server 2008 (NOT WORKING) 
- UAC is 100% disabled and security policies disabled.

If I go to Start->Run->Ping.exe 127.0.0.1 -t and then open Task Manager I see PING.EXE opened under Administrator running in Session ID 2.

If I run it using Process.Start it opens up under SYSTEM in session 0 and is invisible.
If I run it using StartProcessAndBypassUAC it opens up under SYSTEM in session 1.

While it is opening it up in session 1 in both cases, I believe I am unable to see it because administrator is working in session 2 and ping is off in session 1.

How can I open up ping.exe in session 2 in server 2k8?

Comment: Did you try your application under a `mstsc /admin` remote session? We have some monitoring software that creates its windows under the Local System account and this is the only way to see them.

Comment: @sean - best not to say things like "this is time sensitive" on SO. You generally get answers flooding in fairly quickly regardless of how urgent this is for you :). Also the wall of code should really be reduced to just the essence of the problem, you're more likely to get answers that way.

Comment: Haha, yeah, I'll edit the intro, sorry, and trim the code a bit. @David -- I'll try this, too, thanks!

Comment: You seem to make it a point to *not* check for error returns.  Of course you don't know why it doesn't work.  Throw an exception so you can't ignore an error.

Comment: @David Tried using mstsc /admin and didn't notice any difference. Thanks for your suggestion, though! Hopefully disabling UAC and logging in as admin are doing the same things... or close enough.

Comment: @Hans What would my exceptional case be? I stepped through the program on Win 7. I looked into the CreateProcessAsUser and it returns non-zero for success, 0 for failure. If I log that this is failing what should my next step be?

Comment: I remember using this approach to start processes under the logged on user from within Session 0 under the SYSTEM account. But there were problems with it under Server 2008. Now we have two processes communicating via named pipes which process to start. We never found out what the change in Windows was. But I suspect they wanted to close a security hole although as SYSTEM user you should be able to do anything.

Comment: @Alois Could you elaborate more on your solution for Server 2008? Would be nice to have an alternate solution to explore.

Comment: It is simple: Do start when the user logs on (e.g. autostart key) a process which does listen on an interpocess communication object (e.g. named pipe, socked, shared memory, ...). The process under the system account can then send commands to the listening process in user space which executes the requested action e.g. to start a specific process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never came to a solid conclusion on how to automatically detect a user's ID when logged in remotely. Suspect this is a security concern.

Comment: Did you find a solution or any workaround for this ? I'm stuck with almost a same scenario

Comment: Nope! Everything I read said you have to have physical access to the machine to be able to detect the UID.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem when I tried a working C# application on Windows Server 2008 for the first time.  When I would try to launch a process it just wouldn't.

What solved my problem was instead of relying on the working directory, I used the complete path to the executable.

Give this a try

```
applicationName = @"C:\some\dir\putty.exe " + address;
```

Comment: I will try, but you would think that something as basic as ping or telnet would not need a full directory path. One moment. EDIT: I tried -- no dice, ping and telnet do not show up as running processes using full path.